# Accessing an SVN repository from C/C++ e.g. read objects from SVN, their version nbrs etc

Tags: c

I need to be able to read the contents of an SVN repository from a C/C++ routine. I have found Apache's official [SVN minimal client example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/examples/minimal_client.c)! but I can't get it to compile. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

I have downloaded apr-1.7.0-win32-src & subversion-1.12.0 in order to get the header files required in the example source.

I created an application console project in VS2015 and saved the source as a .c object.

If I build with Precompiled headers on I get the following error
Error   C1853   'Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)

If I switch precompiled headers off I get loads of unknown hex character errors...

[image: Error list and source line in error]

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: 0x40's "@". Something's very wrong here with your environment. Sadly it's unlikely we could resolve it remotely. You should consider going into a chatroom and asking for someone to walk through it with you.

Comment: Can be an encoding issue, try open it into a simple text editor and see if there are any special characters

Comment: Since you work in Visual Studio consider using C# and NuGet package SharpSvn.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can you suggest a suitable chatroom. I'm new to all this